# Class selector vs Element selector in Angular 2

Tags: angular

What is the difference between having a custom element as selector metadata vs referring through a class name?

```
@Component({
selector: 'main-container',
...
})

vs

@Component({
selector: '.main-container',
...
})
```

Are there advantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is nothing. 
Just a one difference is that how you use it.

In custom element selector you access it by `<my-component></my-component>`

And in class selector you add class to element and angular will inject into it.

**Regarding advantage**

I will recommend using element selector as it is more readable.